# How can i change background color of my layout by clicking a Button

Tags: android

How can i change background color of my layout by clicking on a `Button` ?

This is my code :

```
Button color_change;
LinearLayout layout;
int value = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    color_change = (Button)findViewById(R.id.color_btn);
    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LL);

    color_change.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (value == 1) {
                 layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            else if (value == 2) {
                 layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else if (value == 3) {
                 layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            }
            else if (value == 4) {
                 layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                 value = 0;
            }
            value++;
        }
    });
```

But i want replace if else condition with other code , because this code is complex and i want short code.
So any one suggest me, how can i short my code ?

Comment: No what is your problem this code is running nice..

Comment: I know this is good but i want to short my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use like this...

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch(value)
                {
                case 1:layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 2:layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case 3: layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                    break;
                case 4:layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                 value = 0;
                    break;              
                }

                value++;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

put all color into a array and in onclick method get particular color from the array and set it like

```
 int color[]=new int[]{Color.BLUE,Color.RED,Color.GRAY};

  color_change.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (value <color.length) {
             layout.setBackgroundColor(color[value]);
        }
        value++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic. Use the `switch` instead of `else if`s. For the added clarity, you might consider having constants or something as values to `value`, so that you don't have to deal with hard-coded integers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array to store the data:

```
int[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK};
int index = value % colors.length;
layout.setBackgroundColor(colors[index]);
value++;
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of colors you want to use

```
List<int> colorsList = new List<int>();
colorsList.add(Color.RED);
colorsList.add(Color.WHITE);
colorsList.add(Color.BLUE);
colorsList.add(Color.GREEN);
//here you can add other colors to list

Iterator<int> colorIterator = colorsList.iterator();
```

function to get next color

```
int getNextColor()
{
   if(colorIterator.hasNext())
   {
      return colorIterator.next();
   }
   else
   {
      colorIterator = colorsList.iterator();
      return colorIterator.next();
   }
}
```

and here is your listener

```
color_change.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

             int color = getNextColor();

             layout.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
});
```